# PHP MySQL form validation

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently working on a project with php and mysql. I'm very new to PHP and I want to be able to check the form for errors before the form action is completed. (The form action is sending information to mySQL database).

```
if(isset($_POST['SendOrder'])) {  

$FirstName1Err = $LastName1Err = $Email1Err = $Phone1Err = $productsErr = $Size1Err = $Quantity1Err = $Price1Err = ""; 

if (empty($_POST['FirstName1'])) { 
$FirstName1Err = "Your first name is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['LastName1'])) { 
$LastName1Err = "Your last name is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['Email1'])) { 
$Email1Err = "Your email is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['Phone1'])) { 
$Phone1Err = "Your phone number is required"; }  

if (empty($_POST['products'])) { 
$productsErr = "Choosing a product is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['Size1'])) { 
$Size1Err = "Choosing a size is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['Quantity1'])) { 
$Quantity1Err = "Choosing a quantity is required"; } 

if (empty($_POST['Price1'])) { 
$Price1Err = "Choosing a price is required"; }

}  

session_start(); 
require 'NFTconnect2.php';  

$epr=''; 
$msg=''; 

if(isset($_GET['epr'])) 
$epr=$_GET['epr']; 



if($epr=='save')
    { 
        $FirstName1 = $_POST['FirstName1']; 
        $LastName1 = $_POST['LastName1'];  
        $Email1 = $_POST['Email1'];  
        $Phone1 = $_POST['Phone1'];  
        $products = $_POST['products'];  
        $Size1 = $_POST['Size1'];   
        $Quantity1 = $_POST['Quantity1'];   
        $Price1 = $_POST['Price1'];

 $a_sql=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES('','$FirstName1','$LastName1', '$Email1', '$Phone1', '$products', '$Size1', '$Quantity1', '$Price1')"); 

        if($a_sql)
            $msg='Your order was successful!'; 
        else 
            $msg= 'Your order was not successful! '; 

    }
```

Basically my question is: How can I write an "if" statement so that I can check the form for validations first and then if the validations pass, then I can run the second part of the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: your session_start() should put ai the bigin of the file.

Comment: if($err1 || $err2 || ...)

Comment: Have a look at my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed a little problem in my answer. Please check the edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable at the beginning called `$hasError = false;`

For each line you add an error, set `$hasError = true;` like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['FirstName1'])) { 
$FirstName1Err = "Your first name is required"; 
$hasError = true;} 

if (empty($_POST['LastName1'])) { 
$LastName1Err = "Your last name is required"; 
$hasError = true;} 

//ETC
```

Then, wrap the second part of your code in an `if` like so:

```
if (!$hasError) {  //If hasError is still false
  //Do stuff
}
```

I do feel obliged to mention that there are much more efficient ways of validating each field, though this was not your concern nor your question, so I'll leave my answer as is :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking if all your `input`s are empty on post from a bunch of `if` statements, put all of the names of your `input`s into an array:

```
$required = array('input1', 'input2', 'input3'); // change input1, input2... to what you require
```

Then, use a `foreach` loop to check back and see whether or not any inputs are empty (which are inside of the `$required` array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required){
        $errors = true; // set errors to true
        echo $key . 'Is required.' // output error
    }
}
```

Now, to check if validation has passed, just simply check if `$errors` is not set.

```
if(!$errors){
    // validation passed
}
```

Obviously, you can tailor this code to your needs. But, if you need any help, just comment and I'll try my best to help you figure it out :)

Hope this helps and saves you a bit of time!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using of Javascript for validation instead of doing it on the back end.

Example:

function validateForm() {
    var validateFname = document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName1"].value;
    if (validateFname == null || validateFname == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Client side validation can't be trusted, he would still need to do backend validation

Comment: not on what his trying to do... hahaha